# Installing FortiClient on MacOS: Failed to connect to the update server

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

After downloading the FortiClient (v5.6) application for MacOS Sierra (10.12.6) and running the FortiClientUpdateInstaller.dmg, the installer ran, but ended in a timeout with the message:

> Failed to connect to the update server

The application dmg file was obtained from: http://www.forticlient.com/downloads

How do I install it? Is there an offline/full-installer version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way around this was to run the FortiClientUpdateInstaller in the Downloads folder, then copy the FortiClientUpdate.app into the Applications folder.

Once it was copied there, I right-clicked and selected "Show Package Contents".

Inside, I navigated to /Contents/MacOS and double clicked the FortiClientUpdate file (108KB). As it ran and connected successfully to the server to download, a terminal window opened and showed the diagnostics.

After it was properly downloaded, I was able to install as per normal.

Inspired by: https://forum.fortinet.com/tm.aspx?m=115822

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion was that the FortiClientUpdateInstaller app was not correctly honouring the proxy settings.
I tried doing what Paul suggested and running with shell environment variables for the proxy set:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://local.proxy.domain:8000
$ export https_proxy=http://local.proxy.domain:8000
```

Then running the app in that shell but it still failed:

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:49: Error: unsupported compressor 8
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist'
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:49: Error: unsupported compressor 8
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/AppExceptions.bundle/Exceptions.plist'
20181012 09:12:58.829 [update:INFO] fcn_upgrade:167 firware: FCT100-FW-6.0.1-28
20181012 09:12:59.483 [update:INFO] fcn_upgrade:184 uid: 2282498392
20181012 09:12:59.483 [update:INFO] fcn_upgrade:201 sn: FCT8002282498392
20181012 09:12:59.489 [update:INFO] fcn_upgrade:209 uid2: BEC3AA1352AF566C9E1AE503EE9FF933
20181012 09:12:59.489 [update:INFO] fcn_upgrade:219 hostname: ws22.umd.com.au
20181012 09:12:59.489 [update:INFO] fcn_upgrade:224 os: Mac OS X 10.13.6
20181012 09:12:59.490 [update:INFO] fcn_upgrade:230 language: en
20181012 09:12:59.491 [update:INFO] fcn_upgrade:128 Last update time: 1970-01-01 10:00:00, Last vulnerability scan time: 1970-01-01 10:00:00
20181012 09:12:59.491 [update:INFO] fcn_upgrade:338 Start to download fdni file...
20181012 09:12:59.491 [update:INFO] update_funcs:363 Try to connect to server 173.243.138.98:80
20181012 09:12:59.491 [update:DEBG] fr_comm:657 sock_connect_s: host: 173.243.138.98, port: 80
```

Next, I connected via my phone hotspot to bypass the proxy and the application ran and downloaded the app fine.

Conclusion: The application does not honour the proxy setting on the system.
This is pretty poor from Fortinet IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown FortiClient first before running the update installer.  This fixed the issue for me.

To do so, right click on the FortiClient icon in the taskbar and select 'Shutdown FortiClient'.  Then try again.